# Recordset not opening when exporting data from Excel to Teradata

Tags: excel, odbc, teradata, vba

I am trying to export a table from Excel into a DB using Teradata.  I know I have a connection to the DB, but the recordset is not open and I am getting ERROR 3704 "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed. Here is my code.

```
    Dim FullQry As String
    Dim qry1 As String
    Dim qry2 As String
    Dim qry3 As String
    Dim qry4 As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, nWB As Workbook
    Dim oWS As Worksheet, oExWS As Worksheet
    Dim y As Long, z As Long
    Dim aRange As Range, bRange As Range
    Dim aData() As Variant

    Application.StatusBar = "Pulling actuals data from TeraData"
    DoEvents

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set oWS = wb.Sheets("LastRanSchedule")
' Set data range/array
    With oWS
        y = .Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        z = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        Set aRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(y, z))
        aData = aRange
    End With

'DECLARE VARIABLES FOR CONNECTION
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionTimeout = 120
    cn.CommandTimeout = 120

'DECLARE VARIABLES FOR RECORDSET
    Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
    Set RS = New Recordset

'DECLARE VARIABLES FOR COMMAND 
    Dim cmdSQLData As ADODB.Command
    Set cmdSQLData = New ADODB.Command

'Connect to Teradata
    On Error GoTo errhndlr
    cn.Open "Data Source = EDTDPAP1; Database= PROD_TECHOPS_LMP_SNBX_DB.AAL_Tableau_TestData; Persist Security info=True; User ID=" & UserID & "; Password=" & UserPassword & "; Session Mode=System Default;"
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set cmdSQLData.ActiveConnection = cn
    RS.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    'RS.LockType = adLockOptimistic
    RS.CursorLocation = adUseClient

'Export Data
Dim val As Variant
Debug.Print cn.State
Debug.Print RS.State
For i = 1 To y - 1
   RS.AddNew
    For j = 1 To z
        val = aData(i, j)
        If IsEmpty(val) Then
        Else
            RS.Fields(j) = val
        End If
    Next j
Next i
RS.UpdateBatch
```

Stepping through the code, the error pops up on `RS.AddNew`.  My debug.print codes confirm that my connection is open but the recordset is closed.  I have ran out of ideas and could really use some suggestions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got the recordset to open, although that created another issue but I will post a new question if I need to.  Here is the updated code.  The change is with the RS connection.

```
'Connect to Teradata
    On Error GoTo errhndlr
    cn.Open "Data Source = EDTDPAP1; Database= PROD_TECHOPS_LMP_SNBX_DB.AAL_Tableau_TestData; Persist Security info=True; User ID=" & UserID & "; Password=" & UserPassword & "; Session Mode=System Default;"
    On Error GoTo 0

'DECLARE VARIABLES FOR RECORDSET (THE RESULTS OF THE SQL QUERY)
    Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
    Set RS = New Recordset
    RS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    RS.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    RS.LockType = adLockOptimistic
    RS.Open "SELECT * FROM PROD_TECHOPS_LMP_SNBX_DB.AAL_Tableau_TestData", cn
    Set cmdSQLData.ActiveConnection = cn
```

Answer (score 0):

I use like this.

```
Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConn As String



strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & dbName

Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset


With Rs
    .ActiveConnection = strConn
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Source = "SELECT * FROM table "
    .ActiveConnection = strConn
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open
    For i = 1 To y - 1
        For j = 1 To Z
            Val = aData(i, j)
            If IsEmpty(Val) Then
            Else
                .AddNew
                .Fields(j) = Val
                .Update

            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    .Close
End With
Set Rs = Nothing
```